# undefined method `stringify_keys' Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "DLDTm1X_c-M":String
```

I'm trying to validate uri in the model so that it doesn't accept if it's uri data

Below is from update method in controller:

```
params[:video][:video_duration] = @yt_session.video_by(@video.yt_youtube_id).duration if Video.new(@video.yt_youtube_id).valid?
```

Below is the validation
      validates :yt_youtube_id, :url => false

I'm using

```
gem 'activevalidators'
```

For this validation

What could be wrong with the error and how can we fix this?

Comment: `Video.new` takes a hash of attributes, not a string.

Comment: @sevenseacat make it answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video.new will take a hash not a string as you are doing.